# How to specify port for scp for a remote server?

Tags: ssh, scp, remote

I have two remote nodes that I am trying to send files from one to another.

```
scp remote1:~/testSCP remote2@10.0.1.10:~/
```

I have `~/ssh/config` set up in my local machine so, it is using port `2222` by default.

But the remote1's default ssh port is set to `22` in the ssh config instead of port `2222`. So, to make any external connection via ssh, it uses port `22` by default.

I tried the following which did not work:

```
scp -P 2222 remote1:~/testSCP remote2@10.0.1.10:~/
```

Also tried the following, which also did not work:

```
scp remote1:~/testSCP -P 2222 remote2@10.0.1.10:~/
```

For both I got the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host 10.0.1.10 port 22: Connection refused
lost connection
```

Which is true since `10.0.1.10` is using port `2222` and not port `22`.

How can I specify remote1 to use port `2222` when trying to send files to `10.0.1.10` (remote2) from `remote1`?

#### Update

After trying

```
 scp -3 remote1:~/testSCP remote2@10.0.1.10:~/
```

I get weird behaviour. Even though my password is correct, it is giving me the following output:

```
remote1@10.0.1.9's password: remote2@10.0.1.10's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
remote1@10.0.1.9's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
remote1@10.0.1.9's password:
```

I have not enabled key-less authentication yet.

#### New Update

After trying it in several ways, I was able to do it in my scripts by logging in to the remote1 via ssh from my localhost and then scp from remote1 to remote2. However, this does not answer my question. I intended upon doing it directly from my local machine then transfer files between two instances, which I think is not supported if two instances' ssh daemons are using a different port than the default for ssh connection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341032/scp-with-port-number-specified might help you

Comment: I tried those as I mentioned in my question. Did not seem to work for me

Comment: localhost listening to port 22 but in ssh config its specefied for both remote1 to remote2 to port 2222. Yes, I meant `~/.ssh/config` In remote 1 and remote the default port in ~/.ssh/config is unchanged so its default port 22.
I can edit them, but I would like to do it using a one-liner, instead of editing every ssh config every single time.

Comment: Ok. I'd suggest to edit your question, adding that you can, but aren't willing to, edit your `~/.ssh/config` files. Then, you may `ssh` into one to the remote hosts and issue a simple `scp` from there, or do it in one line with something as `ssh -t -p <remote1 port> user1@remote1 'scp -P <remote2 port> user2@remote2:/source/path /dest/path'`. Also, you won't have to edit `config` files any single time: only once for each couple of hosts (e.g. setting the port for connecting to `remote2` on `remote1`), but of course you may be uncomfortable with this, depending on the number of hosts you have.

Comment: Yes, that does answer your question. "No" _is_ an answer and is _the_ answer, no matter if you like it or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that with a simple remote-to-remote scp [1].

Instead of it, ssh to the 1st remote host and run scp with a port argument from there:

```
ssh -p 2222 ruser1@rhost1 scp -P 2222 /rpath/1 ruser2@rhost2:/rpath/2
```

If you want to do exactly what `scp` is doing, you can also add the `-n -x -oClearAllForwardings=yes` options to `ssh`, though that's usually not needed.

---

[1]: newer versions of `scp` support a uri spec (including a port) instead of `host:path`, but only when using the `-3` option ("pass through the local host").

So you could probably use

```
scp -3 -P 2222 ruser1@rhost1:/rpath/1 scp://ruser2@rhost2:2222//rpath/2
```

(notice that the `/` after the `host[:port]` is not part of the path -- `scp://user@host/file` will refer to `./file` in the `user`'s home directory).

But copying through the localhost is both slower, and in my experience it will hide errors. For instance, this won't print any error message, despite not being able to create any `/foo/bar/baz` file:

```
scp -3 localhost:.bashrc localhost:/foo/bar/baz
```

I did not get to any depth into this -- just avoided it ;-)

---

If someone is not convinced by all this, they can look at the [source code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/e3b6c966b79c3ea5d51b923c3bbdc41e13b96ea0/scp.c#L945):

```
void
toremote(char *targ, int argc, char **argv)
{
   ...
                } else if (host) {      /* standard remote to remote */
                        if (tport != -1 && tport != SSH_DEFAULT_PORT) {
                                /* This would require the remote support URIs */
                                fatal("target port not supported with two "
                                    "remote hosts without the -3 option");
                        }
```

Notice that the `tport` variable is only set by parsing a `scp://` uri, and it simply doesn't exist in versions older than 7.6p1 (Oct 2017).

Comment: Could you explain what `-x -oClearAllForwardings=yes` this option is doing in your answer please? I was also thinking if it can be done using `rsync` instead.

Comment: `-x` disables X11 forwarding and `-oClear..` disables all tcp forwardings (in case any of them were forced via `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`)

Comment: @RakibFiha rsync says: "The source and destination cannot both be remote". Maybe there are tricks around it, but that should be a separate question.

Comment: Now, I got to realise it after your detailed explanation. (y)

Answer (score 0):

A way that does work is setting up an alias in `~/.ssh/config`

Eg,

```
Host destination
Hostname 10.0.1.10
User remote2
Port 2222
```

Now, you can just use `destination` as your 'hostname' instead, saving you from having to specify the hostname/user/port in the actual command.